# Notebook in Azure Databricks Repos cannot show difference

Tags: azure-databricks, databricks-repos

I am trying to commit and push my change to the branch, I cannot load the difference. I haven't changed many cells and each cells doesn't exceed the 500 lines in the notebook file.
I am wondering why this happens and how to solve it?[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per [official documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebooks-use.html#run-a-cell), The maximum size for a notebook cell, both contents and output, is `16MB`.

[image]

Graphing tools like plotly and matplotlib can generate large sets of results that display as large images. You can reduce the notebook size by hiding these large results and images.

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/notebooks/notebook-autosave

Comment: my notebook size is 0.2 MB is very small

Comment: images & results aren't included into the diff